# ReactTable and custom server side data update

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Has anybody ever used this awesome react components processing server side data?

The solution given [here](https://github.com/react-tools/react-table#server-side-data) is excellent if you don't need to manually update the data.

I would need to refresh the data not only when changing page/pageSize/sorting/filtering, but also after some intervalled time, to see if data got changed.

Also I have an extension of the table that allows the user to do a full text search on all columns so I would need to update the data when the user changes the content of the custom search box too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as yours and I started looking for asynchronous tests with ReactJs and I found this article that was very useful. The key part was to use "update" method on the Enzyme component, like below:

```
const items = ['die Straße', 'die Adresse', 'die Nationalität'];

jest.useFakeTimers();

describe('<DelayedList />', () => {
  test('it renders the items with delay', () => {
    const component = shallow(
      <DelayedList items={items} />
    );

    jest.runAllTimers();
    component.update(); // <--- force re-render of the component

    expect(component.state().currentIndex).toEqual(items.length);
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

For more information, see [this medium article](https://medium.com/@DavideRama/testing-async-setstate-in-react-settimeout-in-componentdidmount-434602abd7db).